# C- Trying to pass character into pthread_create, segmentation fault occurring

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

All right, so I've got my 4 pthread creations (I'm creating 4 threads, which will each manage a cardinal direction, north, south, east, or west):

```
if ((rc = pthread_create(&tidn, NULL, threadcode, (void *)'n')) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "thread create failed (%s)\n", strerror(rc)), exit(1);
if ((rc = pthread_create(&tids, NULL, threadcode, (void *)'s')) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "thread create failed (%s)\n", strerror(rc)), exit(1);
if ((rc = pthread_create(&tide, NULL, threadcode, (void *)'e')) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "thread create failed (%s)\n", strerror(rc)), exit(1);
if ((rc = pthread_create(&tidw, NULL, threadcode, (void *)'w')) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "thread create failed (%s)\n", strerror(rc)), exit(1);
```

and I've got my threadcode function

```
void *threadcode(void* dir)
{
char* direction;
struct cart_t *cart = NULL;

direction = (char*)dir;

printf("casted direction %c\n", *direction);

fprintf(stderr, "thread for direction %c starts\n", *direction);
cart = q_getCart(*direction);
while (cart != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "thread for direction %c gets cart %i\n",
        *direction, cart->num);
    monitor_arrive(cart);
    monitor_cross(cart);
    monitor_leave(cart);
    cart = q_getCart(*direction);
}
fprintf(stderr, "thread for direction %c exits\n", *direction);

return NULL;
}
```

For some reason, the threads are created, but midway through the creation, the code seg faults. I'm not sure where it's happening, but I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in the threadcode function, as threads will start to be created but will then fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making serious errors with what you're passing to `pthread_create()`:

1. It expects a `void *`. You are trying to pass it an `int`. This is implementation-defined behavior, and *may* in some cases work sensibly, but it's better to avoid it. Pass it an actual pointer.
2. If you *do* pass an `int`, then you should at least convert it back to an `int` in your thread function. You actually try to convert into a `char *`, which isn't even close to what you passed. You then try to dereference that spurious pointer to get a character, which is why you're segfaulting.

Here's an example of what you should do. Note that you shouldn't be calling functions like `printf()` or `fprintf()` in multiple threads without some kind of synchronization (or `perror()` for that matter, but for a simple example where it will exit immediately anyway, I'll take my chances). You don't show the implementation, but there's a fair chance some of the other functions you're calling should be similarly protected.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t io_mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void * threadcode(void * arg)
{
    const char c = *((char *) arg);

    if ( pthread_mutex_lock(&io_mtx) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't acquire mutex");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Entered thread for '%c'\n", c);

    if ( pthread_mutex_unlock(&io_mtx) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't release mutex");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tidn, tids, tide, tidw;
    static char * dirs = "nsew";

    /*  Create threads  */

    if ( pthread_create(&tidn, NULL, threadcode, &dirs[0]) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't create north thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( pthread_create(&tids, NULL, threadcode, &dirs[1]) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't create south thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( pthread_create(&tide, NULL, threadcode, &dirs[2]) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't create east thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( pthread_create(&tidw, NULL, threadcode, &dirs[3]) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't create west thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*  State that threads are created  */

    if ( pthread_mutex_lock(&io_mtx) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't acquire mutex");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Threads created\n");

    if ( pthread_mutex_unlock(&io_mtx) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't release mutex");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*  Join threads  */

    if ( pthread_join(tidn, NULL) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't join with north thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( pthread_join(tids, NULL) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't join with south thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( pthread_join(tide, NULL) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't join with east thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( pthread_join(tidw, NULL) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't join with west thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./thread
Entered thread for 'n'
Entered thread for 's'
Entered thread for 'w'
Threads created
Entered thread for 'e'
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd figured if all else fails I'd pass in a char*, but I was hoping there was some way to simply pass the character into the thread function without creating a whole variable.

Comment: `printf`, `fprintf` and `perror` are all guaranteed to be thead-safe in POSIX.

Comment: @caf: Thanks, you are correct. Thread-safety isn't always all that's needed - e.g. output may still be randomly interleaved across multiple calls, so manual synchronization may still be required - but in this particular program where we only care about the individual calls, it would be fine as you say.

Comment: I am really curious why the calls like pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock are needed here?

Comment: @Subhajit: As caf mentioned, in this particular case they're not for POSIX systems because the library implements a similar level of protection. But all these calls manipulate a static internal buffer, and the invariants of those internal mechanisms might be briefly invalidated in the middle of a call. If one thread calls a standard IO function at the same time another thread is calling one, then those internal mechanisms can get messed up really fast.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I understand the threads can get messed up if associated with IO functions simultaneouly.